# How to compare last 2 elements of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have an array:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "789"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "800"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "789"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
  6 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
  7 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
]
```

I need to take out the last 2 elements of the array and compare them. I tried using `$getLast2 = array_slice($chart_data, -2, 2, true);` to get the last 2.

```
array:2 [▼
  6 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
  7 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
]
```

Which then splits it. But Im not sure how to compare these 2 elements within this new array. As the last 2 elements which are now `6` and `7` could change as more data is added. I basically need to tell if the first element is great than, less than or equal to the second element.

Comment: compare two array, Which and which?? do you need to compare the 6th and 7th element??

Comment: I need to compare the 2 elements after splice. In this case its the 6th and 7th its basically the last 2 elements within the first array.

Comment: Your answer is waiting for you, check and let me know.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for all you answers. Decided to go with the prev and end built in functions as they were the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function and then [prev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php):

```
if (end($chart_data) == prev($chart_data)) {
    echo 'Two last elements of an array are equal!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have output this array

```
array:2 [▼
  6 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
  7 => array:1 [▼
    "data" => "787"
  ]
]
```

Re-index them to using PHP `array_values()` function

```
$outputedArray = array_values($outputedArray)
 if($outputedArray[0]['data'] > $outputedArray[1]['data'])
     echo "0 index is greater";
```

Comment: its better to use `array_column` and than `array_values`, see at my answer.

Comment: Btw, You're using them both.

Comment: Do you think they really differ? instead of using ```array_column()``` am injecting the key ?

Comment: I am not telling you to change your code, just see what they did, both your and my result is same but you may need to see the magic of `array_column`, i am sure after understanding you will be use it for your entire PHP journey of array.

Answer (score 0):

> Pass last variable as false;
>
> > preserve_keys
> >     Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the numeric array indices by default. You can change this behaviour by setting preserve_keys to TRUE.

```
array_slice($chart_data, -2, 2, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array you obtained from your previous code is called `$splitArray`, then you could do the following:

```
list($array1, $array2) = $splitArray;
if ($array1['data']>$array2['data'])
{
  echo "1st is greater than 2nd<br>";
}
else
{
  echo "1st is not greater than 2nd<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it suits you, you can just use the array_pop to do the comparison in this manner:

```
    <?php
        $array = [
            ["data" => "789"],
            ["data" => "800"],
            ["data" => "789"],
            ["data" => "787"],
            ["data" => "787"],
            ["data" => "789"],
            ["data" => "787"],
            ["data" => "787"],
        ];

    // MAKE A COPY OF THE ORIGINAL ARRAY:
    $arrayCopy      = $array;

    // POP THE LAST ELEMENT OFF THE $arrayCopy AND SAVE IT AS $lastElem:
    $lastElem       = array_pop($arrayCopy);

    // POP THE LAST ELEMENT OFF THE $arrayCopy AGAIN AND SAVE IT AS $beforeLastElem:
    $beforeLastElem = array_pop($arrayCopy);

    // NOW YOU CAN COMPARE THE LAST ELEMENT AND THE ONE BEFORE IT
    if($lastElem == $beforeLastElem){
        echo "The last 2 Elements of \$array are the same";
    }else{
        echo "The last 2 Elements of \$array are not identical.";
    }
```